# ROS 2 Humble Build from Source on Beaglebone Black

Tags: ros2, build-from-source, beagleboneblack

I have been in the process of building ROS 2 Humble from source on a Beaglebone Black.
So far I can build roughly 140 packages, and I am fixing the errors as they come.

Has anyone here been able to successfully build ROS 2 Humble on a Beaglebone Black?(Using Ubuntu 22.04.3)

Thank you

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.